# Letter 'M' is bolder than the rest of the other text

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, windows-xp, font-face

Not sure what is causing this.

I tested this on my W7 computer at home in Chrome, FF, and IE, with no issues. I have also looked it up on my Droid, still no issues.

I'm at work on a XP machine, and this is how it displays in Chrome:

[image]

It displays fine on my XP machine in FF and IE.

Any clues?

Edit: Page upon request: [www.terrencebowman.com](http://www.terrencebowman.com) (Still in development, obviously)

Comment: Could we see your code? A demo to try would be great.

Comment: Can you also provide a link to the actual page?

Comment: Looks like anti-aliasing gone wrong.

Comment: Added the page. Not sure why I'm being downvoted?

Comment: are you using the latest version of Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome 21, Windows XP:

[image]

it seems fine to me.

EDIT: It is an antialiasing "issue". When using standard antialiasing (Cleartype off), the page looks the same as in your screenshot (Chrome and IE6, IE7, IE8). IE9 and IE10 browsers completely ignore system-wide antialiasing setting and force cleartype on, so it's the reason you don't see corrupted text on your machine.

1. You can simply ignore this issue, or...
2. You can try to use smaller font (font-size: 17px) instead of 18px
   *font-size: 17px with cleartype off:*
   [image]
3. I found a workaround: just use `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` on your p tags.
   This forces Chrome to render the tag (incl. text, transitions) with GPU.
   PS: be careful, translateZ is sometimes buggy, don't use it on a Mac when not necessary

Comment: Interesting. So there is really no way around this issue. It's up to the users to fix it on their end? The 4 in 24 is missing on my contact page. Really odd. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate the extra effort! I'll consider re-sizing things so that it gets rid of it.